# Is it possible to make an Android Layout, without just widgets?

Tags: android, xml, layout, widget

Just something I have been thinking about. It is possible to create an android layout with just a TextView widget and no Layout code (e.g: inearLayout, ScrollLayout), but if I try to add anything else to the XML file all sorts of errors start popping up. Is it possible to create a Layout with just widgets?

Also, if it is, how?

Comment: I dont think its possible. But why would you want to do this?

Comment: I'm messing around with some stuff and if I can have widgets without setting a layout, then it may help. Just curiosity more than anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible inside of an XML layout to have a layout of purely widgets and no ViewGroups. You would for one be creating an invalid XML doc (multiple roots since a widget cannot contain other widgets). Also you need a ViewGroup to hold multiple Views. You can create a merge and then decide on the view group later, however that is just a substitute for a ViewGroup. However it is the closest thing to an XML layout with only widgets in it, surrounded by a merge element as the root xml tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to create layout with a **single** `View` (e.g. `TextView`). But if multiple Views are required you neeed to wrap them with a `ViewGroup` (e.g. `LinearLayout`)